# Getting 404 http code while calling the API from console application in c#

Tags: c#, windows, console-application, webapi

I am trying to call the third party API with API Key as a Basic Authentication. But I am getting the 404 status code 'Content Not Found'. Same API i am calling from Postman and it is giving the result to me.

The code below i am using to call the API through Console Application

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
var authCredential = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AppSettings.PayWayApiKey);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(authCredential));



client.BaseAddress = new Uri(AppSettings.PayWayApiBaseUrl);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new 
MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
'GET Method'

'string APIURL = AppSettings.PayWayApiBaseUrl + "/receipts-files/" + 
 DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");'

string APIURL = AppSettings.PayWayApiBaseUrl + "/receipts-files/2022-01-13";
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(APIURL).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{


}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("Internal server Error");

}
}
```

Comment: You can export c# RestSharp query from postman. I would suggest compare that with your configuration

Comment: Compare all your headers generated in code and in Postman, check if Url is being generated correctly and nothing is missing from it. most of the time 404 is thrown when calling URL path or HTTP method is incorrect. check http and https in Url.

Comment: You are setting a base address and passing the same to GetAsync. I think you are ending up with a bad url

Comment: What url do you use when you call from postman?

Comment: @Crowcoder commented the base address setting and using the API URL only but still getting 404

Comment: @Serge https://api.payway.com.au/rest/v1/receipts-files/2022-01-13/

Comment: Use Fiddler to see what the request is trying to use for a URL. Maybe you just have it wrong in your AppSettings?

Comment: @Berkays I can use RestSharp code to call the API?                                                    var client = new RestClient("http://yoururl.com");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(userName, password);

var request = new RestRequest("resource", Method.GET);
client.Execute(request);                                                                                                        Will it work and good to use RestSharp?

Comment: @DiyaRawat Yes you can and it will work. Is it good to use it? That depends on your needs. This is an extra dependecy